# How to mock a delete test in controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

So I am making my first tests in spring boot and I came across a problem. When I execute my tests, the values are actually getting deleted. I would prefer to mock this so that the values do not get deleted.

**My test class:**
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

public class PartyEndpointTest {

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
@DisplayName("Should Not give access to endpoint")
public void ShouldNotGiveAccess() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/parties"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(401));
}

@Test
@WithMockUser("JLardinois")
@DisplayName("Should respond with not found request")//is 401 because first authorized then check if its found
public void shouldNotFindRequest() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/partyy")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
    .status().is(404));
}

@Test
@WithMockUser("JLardinois")
public void ShouldFindRequest() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/parties")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
            .status().isOk());
}

@Test
@WithMockUser("JLardinois")
public void DeleteParty() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/parties/4")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
            .status().isOk());
}
```

In this test class, my delete method from my controller gets tested, but the entity with ID 4 in my database gets deleted when I run this. I do not want this.
Can anyone help me how to mock this, so that nothing gets deleted from my database?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your whole test, you might run your test against your system together with all kinds of injected dependencies instead of just using controllers and everything else mocked

Comment: @Smutje I uploaded it!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not run tests on your real database. Tests should not be related to the environment in any way. If you want integration tests with database, pay attention to [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/), you can choose framework and database what you want. Your test configuration should not contain the actual base values, create test configuration (application.yaml in src/test/resources) if you don't have it.

If you don't want integration test, mock your repository:

```
 @MockBean
 private MyRepository myRepository;
 @Before
 public void init() {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(myRepository).delete(any());
 }
```